# Setting up Rundeck within a Docker container + reverse proxy in my NGINX

Tags: docker, ubuntu, nginx, containers, rundeck

I'm a little new to docker and nginx reverse proxy methodologies so I'm having a bit of trouble understanding my limitations or steps I should take to make this possible. Below I'll list the set up I'm working with and exactly what I would like the product to look like.

_

**Set-up:**

- virtual machine: Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS
- nginx/1.10.3
- docker 20.10.2
- rundeck image (downloaded from [here](https://github.com/jacekkow/docker-rundeck))*

_

**Nginx default.conf file**

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name vmHostname;
return 301 https://vmHostname$request_uri;
}

server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name vmHostname;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/vmHostname.domain.corp.cert;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/vmHostname.domain.corp.key;
return 301 https://vmHostname.domain.corp$request_uri;
}

# Main webserver route configuration
server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name vmHostname.domain.corp;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/vmHostname.domain.corp.cert;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/vmHostname.domain.corp.key;
#===========================================================================#

# Me trying to host a flask app and failing
location /example-app/ {
    rewrite ^/example-app(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://example-app:5000;
    proxy_set_header    Host                $host/example-app;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
}


# Me trying to route rundeck and failing 
location /rundeck/ {
    rewrite ^/rundeck(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://rundeck:4440;
    proxy_set_header    Host                $host/rundeck;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
    auth_request /auth/;
        }
}
```

_

**My Docker Image**

```
User@vmHostname:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled$ docker images
REPOSITORY                                              TAG                IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
appsession_example-app                                  latest             b2afe846d7f5   3 days ago      914MB
nginx                                                   latest             f6d0b4767a6c   2 weeks ago     133MB
jacekkow/rundeck                                        latest             d0023aa3b7a9   10 months ago   701MB
hello-world                                             latest             bf756fb1ae65   13 months ago   13.3kB
python                                                  3.7.4-alpine3.10   f309434dea3a   15 months ago   98.7MB
```

_

**My Docker Containers**

```
User@vmHostname:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE              COMMAND                  CREATED      STATUS      PORTS                    NAMES
d79261bc568d   nginx:latest       "/docker-entrypoint.…"   2 days ago   Up 2 days   80/tcp                   funny_beaver
669e057b2500   jacekkow/rundeck   "/bin/sh -c /run.sh"     2 days ago   Up 2 days   0.0.0.0:4440->4440/tcp   rundeck
```

_

**What I want/need:**

- I would like to have a set up where this vm is used to host flask apps and run rundeck simultaneously. Based on my current understanding (which could be wrong) I have to download an image of rundeck, move it into a container, go into my rundeck configuration file and set up the reverse proxy, viola!?

Right now my rundeck is "up" when I access vmHostname.domain.corp:4440, but I'm not able to go past the log in page. I'm not totally sure where to go from here. Also, I realize I'm just writing rundeck in my reverse proxy but haven't even set up how nginx will communicate with docker to enable the routing.

*Sorry for the long post... just want to make sure I provide all the info... small desperate whisper of help lol*

Answer (score 1):

You need to set on Rundeck `rundeck-config.properties` file the `grails.serverURL` to the NGINX "output" for Rundeck, on the [official image](https://hub.docker.com/r/rundeck/rundeck) you can set it using `RUNDECK_GRAILS_URL` env var.

NGINX conf:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name rundeck-cl;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://rundeck:4440;
     }
}
```

Here a full "dockerized" example that uses the NINGX config above inside the "config" directory, check line 17 of the docker-compose definition:

```yaml
version: "3.7"
services:
  rundeck:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        IMAGE: ${RUNDECK_IMAGE:-rundeck/rundeck:3.3.8}
    container_name: rundeck-nginx
    ports:
    - 4440:4440
    environment:
      RUNDECK_GRAILS_URL: http://localhost
      RUNDECK_SERVER_FORWARDED: "true"
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    volumes:
      - ./config/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
    ports:
    - 80:80
```

Comment: Hey! thanks for your response. I didn't download the official image because no matter what version I tried to download I'd get a "received unexpected HTTP status: 503 Service Unavailable" The github rundeck image I downloaded was surprisingly the only type of image I was able to download.
Is there a way I can do this with the current rundeck image? 
Also, when you say change rundeck-config.properties you mean ssh into the container of the rundeck image and entering: grails.serverURL: vmHostname.Domain.corp:4440 (example)?

Comment: Hi! not, it's a parameter of rundeck-config.properties file, take a look at this: https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/database/mysql.html#configure-rundeck using rundeck official image you can configure it using some env vars, take a look at this: https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/docker.html#environment-variables

Comment: For sure, this looks similar to the normal setup with rundeck.I don't have a yml file for nginx, so I assume the docker-compose you pasted earlier is based on the rundeck files? Sorry, if my responses are so brutally naive, my life was comprehensible before docker containers and composes came into my life.

Comment: hey do you think this one would work? https://hub.docker.com/r/jordan/rundeck
Looks like I can set the env variables and the external url

Comment: looks good but I prefer the official image :P

Comment: Hey I made my docker-compose file and I'm getting with your set up. The only difference is the image declaration mine is: `IMAGE: ${RUNDECK_IMAGE:-jordan/rundeck:latest}` everything else is literally the same, here's the error: _Building rundeck
ERROR: Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: Dockerfile_

Comment: In the same directory of docker-compose file create a new file named "Dockerfile" with the following content: https://pastebin.com/faz8BUfE and try again.